# Scale svg within parent div

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I have exported a circle as svg from illustrator without an artboard.

I now want to create an animation within a parent `div` so that if the circle is viewed on different sized the animation/svg will scale to the right size.

This gives me some headaches. I tried many solutions I found online but they all don't seem to work for some reason. Here is what I did.

```css
body{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    max-width:825px;
    margin: 0 auto;
     position: relative;
}
@keyframes fadeout {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform: scale(0);
        transform-origin: 50% 50%; 
 stroke: #009AFF;
 stroke-width:3;
 stroke-opacity:0; 
    }
    50%{
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 stroke: #009AFF;
 stroke-width:3;
 stroke-opacity:0.5; 
    }
    100%{
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: scale(1);
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 stroke: #009AFF;
 stroke-opacity:1;
 stroke-width:3;
    }
}     

.circle{ 
    animation: fadeout 1.5s ease-in-out 1 both; animation-delay: 0s; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" height="100%" >
            <title>test</title>
            <circle class="circle" cx="199.925" cy="199.927" r="198.425" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"/>
        </svg>
    </div> 
</div>
```

As you can see it creates a massive circle.
This is based upon the following link I found:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/gionkunz/pen/KDvLj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to give your `.container` an explicit size (either absolute or relative).

- eg. `.container{width: 33%;}`

Also, it looks like your `viewBox` is much too small to contain your circle - so specify a larger viewBox too.

- eg. `viewBox="0 0 600 600"`

**Example:**

```css
body{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    width:33%;
    max-width:825px;
    margin: 0 auto;
     position: relative;
}
@keyframes fadeout {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform: scale(0);
        transform-origin: 50% 50%; 
 stroke: #009AFF;
 stroke-width:3;
 stroke-opacity:0; 
    }
    50%{
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 stroke: #009AFF;
 stroke-width:3;
 stroke-opacity:0.5; 
    }
    100%{
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: scale(1);
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 stroke: #009AFF;
 stroke-opacity:1;
 stroke-width:3;
    }
}     

.circle{ 
    animation: fadeout 1.5s ease-in-out 1 both; animation-delay: 0s; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 600" width="100%" height="100%" >
            <title>test</title>
            <circle class="circle" cx="199.925" cy="199.927" r="198.425" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"/>
        </svg>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Nice this almost does what I want it to do. The problem is that I still have a large viewbox. So if the page where the svg is used in get's smaller the viewbox does to and therefor the circle does to. It would be nice if I could scale the viewbox. Thnx tho!

Comment: The viewbox isn't _any_ size really - it's just a relative pen in which the SVG is drawn. In this case, you can control the size of the viewbox on the page by modifying the size of `.container`.

Comment: I'm reading this: https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/ which is very useful so I'm going to try to understand this and then review it again. Thnx so far!

Comment: Okay so I finally understand how the `viewBox` works compared to the `width` and `height` of an `svg` element. Without looking here I came up with exactly the same answer you gave me. So I think I understand it :-) Thanks once again!